# CSS div block causing list misalignment on WebKit browsers

Tags: html, css

I am using PHP to generate lists and when a list item needs more work I put a red bold exclamation mark to the left of the text.  However on WebKit browsers the items with the exclamation mark are indented slightly, something like this:

- item
- item

  - !item

This is a sample of HTML that produces the same problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<style>
#needswork {
        color:#F00;
        font-weight:bold;
        float:left;
}
</style>
<title>Dodgy lists</title>
</head>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.linuxtech.ie"><em>Atlanta</em> - 24 May</a></li>
<li><div id="needswork"></div><a title="Still needs work" href="http://www.linuxtech.ie"><em>Ashgabat</em> - 2 Feb</a></li>
<li><div id="needswork">!</div><a title="Still needs work" href="http://www.linuxtech.ie"><em>Paris</em> - 3 June</a></li>
</ul>
</html>
```

Note that the second item on the list doesn't have any text in the `div` block and it looks fine.  I copied it into [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swim2birds/eWNxy/1/), but the effect is even stranger.

I tried using CSS reset from http://meyerweb.com, but it didn't make any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Well for starters you can't give two elements the same ID, namely `#needswork`

Comment: have you tried reseting your css first, by using something like this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ? What you are seeing is the browsers default styling...

Comment: Works fine in the latest Chrome and Safari (no indent present).

Comment: Sorry, I should have put that in: yes I did try using the CSS reset code and it didn't make any difference.  I'll edit the text above to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`.
2. Remove the `float:left` from your CSS.

Also, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. Use a Class instead.

You can see the fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/g29dz/

Comment: No, span didn't make any difference, the odd effect is still there.

Comment: @PhilipKearns Fixed it. You shouldn't be using floated block elements in lists without good reason. I'd suggest getting a good book on HTML to help with the basics (I'd recommend HEADFIRST HTML -- it's *very* easy to follow).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I know I shouldn't use ID for multiple elements, it just grew from previous code.